# The starting Activity for my Android application is producing an error

Tags: android

As soon as my application starts i.e. first activity error is being shown like unexpected uncut something. It was not happening till today it has started just now and i don't know how
to deal with it Please help.

Comment: Is your capslock key broken? It would help if you would post the exact error message and logcat output.

Comment: Maybe post the code for the activity you think is causing the issue? We don't have much to go on here...

Comment: @Micha - Yep, I had to fix that. I was being yelled at! ;)

Comment: What has changed? Post the error? throw us a bone to help you with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a well aimed shot in the dark: Clean your project. If fully functional code stops working chances are your R library has gotten confused.